# iCal and Organizer - don't send Accepted email

Tags: email, calendar, icalendar

We have a reservation system so when "Your reservation is complete" email is sent, iCal with `METHOD=REQUEST` is attached. In GMail and also Outlook I see a nice widget about adding it to Calendar. So far so good.

However, if I click on Accept, it automatically sends an email to the organizer. And that might spam our email box. So I decided to skip the organizer from iCal. But then I see *Unknown organizer* in the widget.

Is there some way how to set Organizer and also disable sending "User ABC accepted your invitation" email?

Comment: Is this a programming question? (Asking because Stack Overflow is for programming questions.)

Answer (score 1):

May be late, but...

1 Method Request is not right way here... Use method `PUBLISH`
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2446#section-3.2.1

If u want to use Request method. For examle to see attendies..

2 First option

Use RSVP=False in attendee
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.17

Second option

Generate random mail. Fill in organizer section "mailto". Usually servers don't reply, if organiser email is not same as invitation sender email.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not user adding `RSVP` would help, as FALSE is default value. 
When I generate random email, you have in Calendar then link to text to organizer. And it will be invalid one.